# Redirecting output of stack build --exec

Tags: haskell-stack

I'm currently building and running my Haskell program like this:

```
stack build --exec "myProg with some-args" --file-watch
```

which nicely rebuilds and runs the program again when I make a change.

However, I can't figure out how to redirect the program output to a file, *overwriting the file with each restart*. I can do something like

```
stack build --exec "myprog with some-args" --file-watch > out.log
```

(or, because I'm on PowerShell, `stack build --exec [args as before] | Out-File out.log`)

but that will keep appending to the file, so the results of the first execution remains in the file. I tried

```
stack build --exec "myprog with some-args > out.log" --file-watch
```

but that just sends `>` and `out.log` as additional arguments to my program, instead of redirecting output.

How can I redirect output of my program to a file, overwriting the file on each execution, when using `stack build --file-watch --exec`  to run my program?

Comment: Maybe of interest: https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/472

Comment: @ChrisStryczynski: Yeah, I've seen that (as well as the superseeding https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/651#issuecomment-125996680) but neither of those issues mention how to redirect output. (And neither has had any activity since 2015.)